# Yahoo keeps thinking emails I care about are spam

Tags: yahoo-mail

Yahoo keeps filtering too many good emails to my spam folder.  Even when I manually move an email back to my inbox, it seems incapable of learning that I want emails from that sender.  Some of these senders are in my contacts even.  I am not using I separate client, I read my emails in a web browser.

I just missed an important meeting because of it.  Is there a way to fix this?  Or at least turn off spam filtering entirely?

Comment: Per Yahoo-CustomerCare on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/yahoo/) the option to turn off the spam filter is [not available in Yahoo Mail](https://www.reddit.com/r/yahoo/comments/uowwzv/comment/i8jmmyh)

Comment: which email client are you using? please [edit] in to your question. From a personal perspective, I use Thunderbird Mail and spam filtering works well and as expected.

Comment: @graham I read my emails in a web browser.  Have edited my question

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. The [Top Users page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/yahoo-mail/topusers) of [tag:yahoo-mail] shows that in the last 30 days, there has been only one post, this one. I'm considering making a new meta post for new contributors like you asking questions in similar circumstances. Here is a "sneak preview" association bonus for users and users with rep +20 join [chat] to ask for guidance on how to effectively self-help / write good questions. If you are interested, ping me in Google-Fu, our main chat room.